# pygtk-2.24.0 installing with pygobject-3.0

Tags: python-2.7, centos, pygtk, pygobject

I am trying to install pygtk-2.24.0 from source in centos6.8, for that pygobject-3.0 is installed from source and `pkg-config --list-all | grep pygobject` returns `pygobject-3.0 PyGObject - Python bindings for GObject`. Exported `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig', but still the configure script of pygtk returns

> checking for GLIB - version >= 2.8.0... yes (version 2.48.1)
>   checking for PYGOBJECT... no
>   configure: error: Package requirements (pygobject-2.0 >= 2.21.3) were not met:

No package 'pygobject-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.'

It could find glib, but not pygobject

Comment: » Package requirements pygobject-2.0 « : So where is the "package config file" `pygobject-2.0.pc` ? .. If the location is e.g. `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/pygobject-2.0.pc`, then you will have to do : `export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR`

Comment: I have `pygobject-3.0.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`, but no `pygobject-2.0.pc`, do you think I have to install pygobject-2.x version? but the pygtk is the latest and I think pygobject should be a latest one.

Comment: pygobject-3.0.pc : Isn't that a python 3 file ? pygtk-2.24.0 is for python2, I think.  .... Have you found any information saying python3 / pygobject3 ?

Comment: I found a reason, PyGTK 2.24.0 released on Friday 01 April 2011, and may not support newer versions of pygobject, A note is on website "New users are encouraged to use GTK+3 through the PyGObject bindings instead of using PyGTK with GTK+2". Wiki says PyGTK will be phased out with the transition to GTK+ version 3 and be replaced with PyGObject, but gimp needs pygtk, is it works with PyGObject?